# Not able to add days to a date in a loop more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this code on selected index changed of a dropdownlist which represents months.

```
    DateTime firstDate, lastDate;
    int mon = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex +1;
    int year = 2013;

    GetDates(mon, year,out firstDate , out lastDate);
    DateTime f = firstDate;
    DateTime d2 = firstDate.AddDays(7);
    for (;d2.Month  == mon;  )
    {
        d2.AddDays(7);   // value after first iteration is "08-Apr-13 12:00:00 AM"
                        // but beyond first iteration the value remains the same.
    }


    private void GetDates(int mon, int year, out DateTime firstDate, out DateTime lastDate)
    {       
        int noOfdays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, mon);
        firstDate = new DateTime(year, mon, 1);
        lastDate = new DateTime(year, mon, noOfdays);
    }
```

I was hoping that d2 will keep getting incremented by 7 days in each iteration as long as resulting value is in the same month. But it seems that the value increments just once. i.e from 01-Apr-13 12:00:00 AM to 08-Apr-13 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to assign changed date object back to date object `d2` because DateTime object is **immutable**. `AddDays` method returns *new* object instead of changing the object on which it is called so you have to assign it back to calling object.

```
d2 = d2.AddDays(7);
```

**Edit** Why it works for first iteration ?

Because you are intializing the date object by add 7 days before loop.

```
DateTime d2 = firstDate.AddDays(7);
```

Comment: That was quick haha. Thanks it worked. But i still dont understand why it works the first in the first iteration ?

Comment: @Arbaaz you don't start with first date, but firstdate +7. It's not the first iteration, it's before loop.

Comment: oh yes , how silly of me. Thanks I am going to mark this as an answer. As soon as SO allows me to(8 mins).

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be?

```
d2 = d2.AddDays(7);
```